# как проверить функцию odeint() и вывести нормально на график

Tags: python

В общем вопрос такой, я написал метод эйлера и модифицированный эйлера как проверить теперь свою функциию и вывести на общий график с моими методами
Вот код

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as spint
import scipy as sc
def f(x, y):
    return (x**2*np.sin(0.5*y))+2

x0 = 0; y0 = 1; X = 1;
n = 3



def Eyler_mod(x0, y0, f, X, n):#модифицированный метод
    h = X/n                    #Эйлера - с средней точкой
    x = np.zeros(n+1)
    y = np.zeros(x.shape)
    x[0] = x0
    y[0] = y0
    for i in range (n):
        x[i+1] = x[i]+(i+1)*h/2
        y[i+1] = y[i] + (h/2)*f(x[i], y[i])
    return x, y

def Eyler(x0, y0, f, X, n):
    h = X/n
    x = np.zeros(n+1)
    y = np.zeros(x.shape)
    x[0] = x0
    y[0] = y0
    for i in range (n):
        x[i+1] = x[i]+(i+1)*h
        y[i+1] = y[i] + h*f(x[i], y[i])
    return x, y
print(Eyler(x0, y0, f, X, n))
x, y = Eyler(x0, y0, f, X, n)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.grid()
x, y = Eyler_mod(x0, y0, f, X, n)
plt.plot(x, y,marker='o',color="red")
plt.grid()
print(Eyler_mod(x0, y0, f, X, n))
```

Comment: Вывести так же, как и любую другую функцию. А что значит "проверить"?

Comment: @Эникейщик я это сделал таким образом `t = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
y0 = [1.0,1.0]
sol = spint.odeint(f, y0, t)
plt.plot(t, sol[:, 0],marker='o',color="green")` Но я не понимаю правильно ли я задал t и y0